# Digital Potentiometer controlling DC motor speed problem: voltage won't step properly

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, digital-potentiometer

I'm building a rheometer to measure the viscosity of liquids. I'm using a 4.5-10v DC motor which needs to be accurately controlled by a Raspberry Pi (the speed and torque must scale, so PWM is out).

[image: The circuit]

I have been trying to control the motor with a 10k digital pot (MCP4131) in a voltage divider with a transistor to control the voltage through the motor.

In theory, the voltage should (as the pot sweeps through its range, 129 steps) vary between ~2.6v and ~10.5v.

In practice, the voltage only varies between ~7v to ~5v, reaching its minimum after only ~25 steps and then staying constant for the remaining 100 or so steps.

What is going wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

This has been the bane of my life the last few weeks, any help would be greatly appreciated. If anything is unclear I will clarify as best I can.

EDIT: MCP3141 -> MCP4131

Comment: Voltage measured at what point? I suspect if you disconnect the transistor and measure the W pin in isolation you'll get what you want. The transistor side of the circuit is very badly designed for speed control, and I'm not convinced by your reasoning in ruling out PWM?

Comment: Voltage measured from the emitter of the transistor to ground.

How could it be improved? What would be a better circuit?

Comment: You really should have a [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) across that motor.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, yes it should be MCP4131. I forgot to stick the diode in the diagram, but it is there in the physical circuit

Comment: What are the voltages at pins 5 and 7?  Is W stepping properly from one of end to the other?  I would diagnose the software/micro/pot and the motor drive output completely separately.

Comment: How much current can an MCP4131 supply? How much current do you need through the base of the transistor? Can the 12 V source supply enough current for the motor?

Comment: A quick read of the digital pot data sheet suggests that +12v on "Pot A" pin is *way outside* acceptable range of zero-to-Vcc. In your case Vcc=3.3v.

Comment: Before even trying to fix the circuit, motor speed and torque definitely does not scale with applied voltage in a simple way and there are other variables involved (like the load).

Comment: "I'm using a 4.5-10v DC motor" - do you have any other data for that motor, eg. stall current, operating current at 10V?

Comment: "I forgot to stick the diode in the diagram" - don't worry, you don't need a flyback diode in this circuit.

Comment: @BruceAbbott If the 12 V supply is lost (power failure, a lead falls out, etc.) won't the voltage spike damage things?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Why isn't the flyback diode necessary?

Comment: "Why isn't the flyback diode necessary?" - Two reasons. Firstly because inductive back-emf causes a negative voltage which keeps the transistor turned on and suppresses voltage spikes. Secondly, unlike PWM the motor isn't constantly being turned on and off at a high rate, so there are far fewer back-emf events to deal with.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Isn't "fewer back-emf events to deal with" a bit like playing Russian roulette with only one cartridge instead of two?

Comment: @Andrew Morton  This is _not_ the same as a common Emitter circuit where back-emf rises until the transistor breaks down. The transistor is turned on so back-emf voltage is reduced and VCeo(sus) won't be reached. A few current spikes every now and then won't cause it to heat up like continuous PWM would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you are trying to control a voltage of up to 10.5V with a digital pot that can only handle 5.5V. The [MCP4131 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22060b.pdf) doesn't make it very clear, but the pot only works properly when its terminal voltages stay within the supply rails (Vss to Vdd). If they go outside this range then internal protection diodes will attempt to clamp the voltages to Vss or Vdd.

Another potential problem is that the pot's output voltage drops as more current is drawn from it. Pot resistance varies depending on where the wiper is, so the output will be nonlinear if significant current is drawn. Also as the motor draws more current the transistor will draw more Base current, which drops more voltage across its Base- Emitter junction as well as increasing voltage drop in the pot.

If you want to stick with this design idea then you need to either get a pot that can handle higher voltage, or reduce the pot voltage to 5V and amplify it with an op amp like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fasD4f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 and R4 produce a voltage gain of 2.1, which amplifies 5V to 10.5V. Q1 is included in the feedback loop to compensate for voltage drop across its Base-Emitter junction, ensuring that the motor voltage follows the input voltage linearly. The op amp's inputs draw virtually no current, so the pot's output voltage stays constant even when the motor is drawing high current. The AD820 can output up to 15mA which the BD243 would amplify by ~100, providing up to 1.5A to drive the motor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't have an AD820, but I have a couple LM358s. They can source 20mA, so they should work instead, right?

Comment: Yes, an LM358 should work.